# `no matching function for call` upon parameter pack recursive expansion

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

Please consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>


template <int I, typename T, typename ...Args>
struct foo {
    static void bar(const T& t0, const T& t1, const Args&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "( " << t0 << ", " << t1 << " ) ";
        foo::bar(args...);
    }
};

template <int I, typename T>
struct foo<I, T> {
    static void bar(const T& t0, const T& t1)
    {
        std::cout << "( "<< t0 << ", " << t1 << " ) " << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    foo<1, int, float>::bar(0, 1, 18.f, -7.f);
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect it to compile fine and output the following (or so) at runtime:

```
( 0, 1 ) ( 18, -7 )
```

However, this code produces the following output via `g++ -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra parampack.cpp` (GCC 5.3.0):

```
parampack.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
parampack.cpp:23:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo<1, int, float>::bar(int, int, float, float)’
     foo<1, int, float>::bar(0, 1, 18.f, -7.f);
                                             ^
parampack.cpp:6:17: note: candidate: static void foo<I, T, Args>::bar(const T&, const T&, const Args& ...) [with int I = 1; T = int; Args = {float}]
     static void bar(const T& t0, const T& t1, const Args&... args)
                 ^
parampack.cpp:6:17: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided
parampack.cpp: In instantiation of ‘static void foo<I, T, Args>::bar(const T&, const T&, const Args& ...) [with int I = 1; T = int; Args = {float}]’:
parampack.cpp:23:25:   required from here
parampack.cpp:9:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo<1, int, float>::bar(const float&)’
         foo::bar(args...);
                 ^
parampack.cpp:6:17: note: candidate: static void foo<I, T, Args>::bar(const T&, const T&, const Args& ...) [with int I = 1; T = int; Args = {float}]
     static void bar(const T& t0, const T& t1, const Args&... args)
                 ^
parampack.cpp:6:17: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
```

I tried all kind of variations and permutations like:

```
template <int I, typename T, typename U, typename ...Args>
struct foo {
    static void bar(const T& t0, const T& t1, const U& u0, const U& u1, const Args&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "( " << t0 << ", " << t1 << " ) ";
        foo::bar(u0, u1, args...);
    }
};
```

...but I cannot seem to make it compile and **I'm not really sure what exactly happens**.

Why doesn't the compiler figure out what functions to instantiate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start with, you have the wrong number of arguments - as the compiler suggests. `foo<1, int float>::bar()` has the signature:

```
static void bar(int const&, int const&, float const& );
```

That's 3 arguments. You're passing in 4. Hence the straightforward error.

What you apparently are trying to do is to pick 2 arguments at a time. In this case, the trailing arguments in `bar` are not the same as the trailing arguments in `foo`, so you want:

```
template <int I, typename T, typename ...Args>
struct foo {
    template <class... Extra>
    static void bar(const T& t0, const T& t1, const Extra&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "( " << t0 << ", " << t1 << " ) ";
        foo::bar(args...); // <== (*)
    }
};
```

That will bring in the second problem: the recursive call to `foo::bar()`. The `foo` there is the injected-class-name of the primary template. That will never actually get you into your base case specialization. So there, you want:

```
foo<I, Args...>::bar(args...);
```

Comment: "What you apparently are trying to do is to pick 2 arguments at a time. In this case, the trailing arguments in bar are not the same as the trailing arguments in foo" -> that what was confusing me! Now I can adapt it to any type and number or arguments. Thank you!